# Why didn't Erica suck the vampire venom out of Ethan instead of Sarah?

Tags: my-babysitters-a-vampire

In *My Babysitter's A Vampire*, Season 1 Episode 13 ("Re-Vamped"), we see that Sarah sucks the venom out of Ethan, although reluctantly as she did not want to become a full vampire, but Erica doesn't. Why didn't Erica suck the venom out of Ethan instead of Sarah if she was out of the trance that Jesse put her under? Wouldn't that make more sense?

Comment: I don't know.  maybe Erica just doesn't like Ethan enough.